# Obtaining small images that intersect with shapefile on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I am new to Google Earth Engine and am trying to obtain small images that intersect with my shapefile. My shapefile contains 1250 squares of size ~2.5km x ~2.5km.

I am trying to find a way to iterate over my shapefile and obtain not a mosaic of images, but 1250 GeoTiff images that correspond to these 1250 squares.

Is there a way to do so?

When I run the code, my EarthEngine crashes. I would like to obtain a resolution of 10m/pixel (S-2's maximum resolution) and upload them to Google Drive. Also, I do not need all the possible images but just the median/a combined image that best represents the satellite image in RGB.

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

// my shapefile that contains the squares are here:
var survey = ee.FeatureCollection('users/danielboeyks/surveyfile');
var geom_country = survey.geometry().dissolve().bounds();
Map.addLayer(survey);


function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2') // searches all sentinel 2 imagery pixels...
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 20)) // ...filters on the metadata for pixels less than 10% cloud
  .filterDate('2017-01-01' ,'2017-12-31') //... chooses only pixels between the dates you define here
  .filterBounds(geom_country) // ... that are within your aoi
  .map(maskS2clouds)
  

var medianpixelsclipped = collection.median() // This finds the median value of all the pixels which meet the criteria. 

// Now visualise the mosaic as a natural colour image. 
Map.addLayer(medianpixelsclipped, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 1, gamma: 1.5}, 'Sentinel_2 mosaic')

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(medianpixelsclipped, 'satellite-poverty-mapping',{
  description: 'ph_grid',
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  region: geom_country
});

//codecreds: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYFv3j2tE5U&ab_channel=EAMENAProject
//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing my script I considered a shapefile with only 8 features. With your parameters (dates range) for Sentinel 2 Image Collection, 54 images were filtered for this shapefile. So, iteration over my shapefile would produce 432 clipped individual images. I selected the first image of complete list for visualization purpose. Full [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1fb395591dab9ade297d2c7859f0e757) looks as follows:

```
// Load feature collection from assets
var area = ee.FeatureCollection("users/joseguerreroa/vector_files_utah/polygon8");

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2') // searches all sentinel 2 imagery pixels...
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 20)) // ...filters on the metadata for pixels less than 10% cloud
  .filterDate('2017-01-01' ,'2017-12-31') //... chooses only pixels between the dates you define here
  .filterBounds(area) // ... that are within your aoi
  .map(maskS2clouds);

print("collection", collection);

Map.centerObject(area);
Map.addLayer(area, {'color':'blue'}, 'polygon8');

print('First feature:', area.first());

var featsList = area.toList(area.size());

var list_images = collection.toList(collection.size());

var clipedImages = list_images.map(function lookOverColl (e) {
  
  var clipFeats = featsList.map(function clipImage(ele){
  
    var new_list = ee.List([]);
    
    var img = ee.Image(e).clip(ele);
    
    new_list = new_list.add(img);
  
    return new_list;

  });
  
  return clipFeats.flatten();
  
}).flatten();

print(clipedImages);

var img_clip = clipedImages.get(0);

print(img_clip);

Map.addLayer(ee.Image(img_clip), 
{bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0.09, max: 0.8,},
'Sentinel_2 image');
```

After running it in GEE code editor, I got result of following image.

[image]

As expected, it can be observed the first individual image completely displayed (with masked clouds) and a list of 432 images printed in Console of GEE code editor.

**Editing Note:**

As I pointed out in my comment, it is necessary to map over different slices with different indices of Image Collection. So, following [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/10eabb6b2e33935e01d3029879dcda86) can do that for my example with only 8 features. Adapt it for your particular situation.

```
// Load feature collection from assets
var area = ee.FeatureCollection("users/joseguerreroa/vector_files_utah/polygon8");

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2') // searches all sentinel 2 imagery pixels...
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 20)) // ...filters on the metadata for pixels less than 10% cloud
  .filterDate('2017-01-01' ,'2017-12-31') //... chooses only pixels between the dates you define here
  //.filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', '12TUK')
  .filterBounds(area) // ... that are within your aoi
  .map(maskS2clouds);

print("collection", collection);

Map.centerObject(area);
Map.addLayer(area, {'color':'blue'}, 'polygon8');

var featsList = area.toList(area.size());

var list_images = collection.toList(collection.size());

var clipedImages = list_images.map(function lookOverColl (e) {
  
  var clipFeats = featsList.map(function clipImage(ele){
  
    return ee.Image(e).clip(ele);

  });
  
  return clipFeats;
  
}).flatten();

print("Clipped Images", clipedImages);

var count = clipedImages.size();

var count_feats = area.size();

var list_feats = ee.List.sequence(0, count_feats.subtract(1));

//build indices list for mapping clipped images
var list_indices = list_feats.map(function group (ele) {
  
  return ee.List.sequence(ele, count.subtract(1), 8); 
  
});

print("Indices List", list_indices);

//mapping over indices list for retrieving list of clipped images by features
var select_images = list_indices.map(function group_images (ele) { //ele is a list of indices each n
                                                                   //features
  var list = ee.List(ele);
  
  var list_images = list.map(function sel_img (e) {
    
    return clipedImages.get(ee.Number(e));
    
  });
  
  return list_images;
  
});

print("Selected images by group", select_images);

//group a list of images for converting it in Image Collection and then in median image
var median_feats = list_feats.map(function median_group (ele) {
  
  return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(select_images.get(ee.Number(ele))).median();
  
});

print("Median for each Feature", median_feats);

//for verification purpose
var first_median = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(select_images.get(0)).median();

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["B4","B3","B2"],
                     "min":0.1046,
                     "max":0.1875,
                     "gamma":1};

Map.addLayer(first_median, imageVisParam, 'first median');

var second_median = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(select_images.get(1)).median();

var imageVisParam2 = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["B4","B3","B2"],
                     "min":0.0669,
                     "max":0.2159,
                     "gamma":1};

Map.addLayer(second_median, imageVisParam2, 'second median');
```

After running it in GEE code editor, it was obtained result of following image. For testing validity of result, there was displayed only two median images. It worked for me. In your case, due to a big number of features and images, it could be necessary to export directly to Google Drive.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How can I median out the images (I only want one combined image per polygon from Sentinel 2) & extract the batch of images into Google Drive? I tried this: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d3ab748ee3ecb0c2dc1bc49b6f7688bd but i think it gives the error: collection.toList is not a function

Comment: You're welcome. I will see it later (I'm busy now) but, remember, that you have 1250 features and n images in your **Image Collection**. So, for finding the median of n aligned images you need to slice them for each feature each 1250 positions. It is necessary to map a list of images each 1250 positions.

Comment: I found out a solution. However, you should post your comment as another question because it is necessary to map over different slices with different indices of Image Collection.

Comment: Thank you! I've edited the post/question, if that is ok?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my answer too.